# Remove indentation in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I want remove the space in my table of contents of `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be 
used which are important and deserve to appear in the 
Index\index{Index}.
 \subsection{subsection}
Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} 
will also show up. Terms in the index can also be 
nested \index{Index!nested}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special 
word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), these lengths are managed by `\cftXindent` where `X` includes `chap` (for `\chapter`), `sec` (for `\section`) and `subsec` (for `\subsection`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \section
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsection
% \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsubsection

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `titletoc`:

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0.2pt}
\titlecontents{section}
  [2.5em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.5em}}
  {}
{\hfill\thecontentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [2.5em]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}\mdseries}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.5em}}
  {}
{\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be
used which are important and deserve to appear in the
Index\index{Index}.
 \subsection{subsection}
Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others}
will also show up. Terms in the index can also be
nested \index{Index!nested}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special
word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i align the numbers vertically and also the text vertically?